# I dont know how it called but i want event can execute from backend with non blocking user action in php or laravel

Tags: php, laravel, events

Actually i am new to php and laravel I have question about creating any function can execute from Backend only and that function should not impact users any action for example if I upload xlsx file and and it will answer success uploaded and my function that i wanted should work on that xlsx file just one time I tried laravel event&listener but it answers when both upload and listener success so guys if something is not clear let me know i will explain

Comment: lookup queues and job on laravel

Comment: @N69S Thank you it saved my time that is what i wanted